# How to use VBA to color and frame cells with value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to color and frame a column in data. There are blank rows inside. I only want to color the cells with value. The data position might change, so I want to use an input box to color and frame .

The data will be like this. The select range would be column B.

```
1   A
2   B
3   
4   A
5   B
6   
7   A
8   B
9   
10  A
11  B
12  
13  A
14  B
15  
16  A
17  B
18  
19  A
20  B
21  
22  A
23  B
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need VBA - you could use Conditional Formatting.  Highlight the entire column B, then go to "Conditional Formatting" under Home tab.  Click "New Rule" and choose the last one in the list, "Use a formula to determine which cells to format.", enter this in the box `=$B1<>""`. Then click "Format" and go to "Fill" - choose the color you want, and hit "OK" and "OK". That should do it!

Edit: Ah, about the input box - can you expand on what you want to do with that? What do you mean by using it to "color and frame"?

Comment: I could not add image. Color and frame means that I want to add color on valued cells and also put border on.

Comment: You can do that with the Conditional Formatting, although the frame can only be the "thin" border.